# How to enable password saving in Chrome run by Capybara through Selenium?

Tags: selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a test using Capybara that checks whether Chrome's auto-fill feature works correctly for my web application's login form.  If running the web application in the browser and saving the password after registration, Chrome automatically fills the login form.  However for the automated test, I didn't find a way to make Chrome save the password of the registration form that's been entered by Capybara/Selenium.  It seems like the popup for this isn't even shown.  Is there a way to enable the saving of passwords?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  preferences = {credentials_enable_service: true,
                 password_manager_enabled: true}
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
  capabilities['chromeOptions'] = {'prefs' => preferences}
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome,
                                 desired_capabilities: capabilities)
end
```

The workflow will be like this:

1. start driver
2. enter credentials
3. browser will ask if you want to save them
4. log in in app and log out
5. then try to enter credentials second time

Also probably you will be interested in [capybara-sessionkeeper](https://github.com/kyamaguchi/capybara-sessionkeeper)

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me. What I did exactly: I put the code snippet that registers the driver before my test (but giving it a different name) and set the current Capybara driver to this. Then I ran the test that registers a user in my application. Chromium doesn't show a popup to save the pasword (and doesn't save it itself).